# Cannot Call Mysql store procedure on C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using mysql 5.6 version and C#
I created stored procedure call PWITEMS().

```
delimiter //
create procedure PWITEMS() 
begin 
select Jw_ItemName,Jw_ItemID FROM pawning.jewelry_items;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

When I call that procedure it gives the error:

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.26-log]You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NewPWITEMS' at
>   line 1

My C# code is here:

```
OdbcDataReader dr;
OdbcConnection cnn = new OdbcConnection(Form1.dbconn.str);
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("NewPWITEMS", cnn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cnn.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    cmbJewType.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}

dr.Dispose();
cnn.Close();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show the definition of `NewPWITEMS` procedure? Read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Does the user that you use in your connection string have access to that procedure?

Comment: `call newpwitems`, not just `newpwitems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL the command would be

```
CALL PWITEMS
```

(I note your definition was for PWITEMS, not NewPWITEMS)

See comment below - the ODBC docs specify the correct way is to surround the call with braces : http://vieka.com/esqldoc/esqlref/htm/odbcprocedure_calls.htm

Comment: Did you change to _CALL PWITEMS_

Comment: Or try OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{CALL PWITEMS()}", cnn);